# Convert xlsx to txt tab delimited - Batch process

Tags: excel, vbscript

Im trying to convert a xlsx file into a tab delimited text file, but the output in the text file looks to be random text.  below is my source code.  Any help on get it to output as a tab delimited txt file would be much appreciated.  I used a regular workbook with two columns, with headers but its unable to convert to a tab delimited txt file.

```
Option Explicit

Dim oFSO, myFolder
Dim xlText

myFolder="C:\Projects\scripts\test"


Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
xlText = -4158 'Excel txt format enum
Call ConvertAllExcelFiles(myFolder)
Set oFSO = Nothing

Call MsgBox ("Done!")

Sub ConvertAllExcelFiles(ByVal oFolder)
    Dim targetF, oFileList, oFile
    Dim oExcel, oWB, oWSH

    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set targetF = oFSO.GetFolder(oFolder)
    Set oFileList = targetF.Files
    For Each oFile in oFileList
        If (Right(oFile.Name, 4) = "xlsx") Then
            Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)
            For Each oWSH in oWB.Sheets
                Call oWSH.SaveAs (oFile.Path & ".txt")
            Next
            Set oWSH = Nothing
            Call oWB.Close
            Set oWB = Nothing
        End If
    Next
    Call oExcel.Quit
    Set oExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a VBScript not VBA.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing the FileFormat parameter on SaveAs, so it's not actually converting the Excel file to Text, just adding an extension.

Try changing

```
Call oWSH.SaveAs (oFile.Path & ".txt")
```

to

```
Call oWSH.SaveAs (oFile.Path & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlTextWindows )
```

Comment: Perfect, that did it for me! Thanks you very much Dendarii

Comment: This solution would only work if running the code as VBA.